# ¿Como puedo poner el value de un input desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, radiobutton

mi intencion es crear un radio button desde javascript al momento de apretar el botón, pero no puedo ponerle un valor de texto para que salga al lado del radio button, tengo entendido que modificando el value del boton solucionara el problema pero no se como hacerlo desde Javascript.

```
<script> 
function pregunta2() {
    var botonV = document.createElement("input");
    botonV.setAttribute("type", "radio"); 
    botonV.value = "verdadero";//Aqui es donde no se como asignarle un valor.

    document.getElementById("divPreguntas").appendChild(botonV);
} 
</script>

<div class="col-md-3"><button onclick="pregunta2();">Pregunta  V/F</button></div>

<div id="divPreguntas"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que a lo que te estás refiriendo es el label del radio button. El value es el valor que va a devolver el campo del radio al hacer el submit. La estructura correcta del Radio button seria esto:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" value="verdadero">
  <label for="verdadero">Huey</label>
</div>
```

Por lo tanto en tu código deberías crear el label con la propiedad for con el mismo valor que el value.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Ya, fue un error mio, la mejor manera es hacer eso gracias!